# Auto request without open url on browser

Tags: javascript, php, request

I need to update the database from server, but I have to open url in browser handle.
How can I request to url without open url on the browser?

Comment: Make a cron job in linux

Comment: Ever heared of ajax?

Comment: Why do you have to open a URL in a browser to update a database?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your javascript section: `xmlhttp.open("GET","some_page_name.xyq",true);`

[More Information](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CURL** in PHP
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-init.php

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Or you can use function **file_get_content** in PHP.

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

Or you can use some linux function from PHP

```
system("wget -N -O - 'http://google.com")
```